# Calculate number of exercises in each category in access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables such as: `Category` and `Exercise`. In the first of them I have field names such as: `CategoryID` and `CategoryName`. In the second table there are field names such as: `ExerciseID` `Exercise` and `CategoryID`. I have to calculate the number of exercises in each category. For the exercises with provided data I have:

- addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, enhancemen, 
  running, jumping, pole vault, shot put, literature, grammar.

The query has to output me:

- Maths = 5
- English = 2
- PE = 4

How would I be able to calculate this within query in ms-access?

Comment: Hello. This seems like an impossible to answer question with the provided information. If you can provide a minimal example data set, and the data set you'd expect the query to provide, we'll be able to help.

Comment: @Goose Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a key to join the tables.

In addition to `ExerciseID` and `Exercise`, have a `CategoryKey` column which you can join to the `Category` table through `CategoryID`. Then you'd just query `SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM Exercise WHERE CategoryKey = 1` where 1 is the CategoryID you want to count. You can also do more complex joins in the future if you have new requirements.

Otherwise, you'll have to write a giant goofy sql switch statement, which I don't have much experience with, because it's usually not something you need to use if your table is structured correctly.